# Angular Js File Upload - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to upload image file using angular and php, but I am getting problem at app.service

error line : app.service('fileUpload', ['$https:', function ($https:) {

code

```
      app.service('fileUpload', ['$https:', function ($https:) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
           var fd = new FormData();
           fd.append('file', file);

           $https:.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
              transformRequest: angular.identity,
              headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
           })

           .success(function(){
           })

           .error(function(){
           });
        }
     }]);
```

error

```
question.js:20 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?.....
at angular.js:38
at angular.js:4920
at q (angular.js:403)
at g (angular.js:4880)
at eb (angular.js:4802)
at c (angular.js:1914)
at Sc (angular.js:1935)
at ue (angular.js:1820)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:33367)
at j (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `$https:` to just `$http`

```
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
```